# Can operand stack size differ at given instruction depending on execution history?

Tags: java, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

For example, for method

```
public int f() {
    int k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        k += 2;
    }
    return k;
}
```

`javac` generates the following bytecode:

```
public int f();
Code:
   0: iconst_1
   1: istore_1
   2: iconst_0
   3: istore_2
   4: iload_2
   5: bipush        10
   7: if_icmpge     19
  10: iinc          1, 2
  13: iinc          2, 1
  16: goto          4
  19: iload_1
  20: ireturn
```

At label 4 stack has same size (0), no matter which instruction was previous: 3 or 16.

Is that generally true for bytecode **generated from java code**?

Comment: I don't think your method uses stack.. How about creating a simple recursive function?

Comment: @J.Cheong: JVM bytecode instructions are stack-based. something like `iconst_1` operates on a stack.

Comment: @J.Cheong: I mean not **execution stack**, but **operand stack**. Each method invocation has it's own one, initially empty (as said in asm documentation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a reference to the Antimony's answer, see the 
[JVM specification §4.9.2. Structural Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2) (thank you Holger!):

> - ...
> - If an instruction can be executed along several different execution paths, the operand stack must have the same depth (§2.6.2) prior to the execution of the instruction, regardless of the path taken.

In the first version of this answer, I cited [§4.10.2.1. The Process of Verification by Type Inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.1), which is for class files that do not contain `StackMapTable` attributes (version number of 49.0 or below):

> ... The verifier ensures that at any given point in the program, no matter what code path is taken to reach that point, all of the following are true:
>
> - The operand stack is always the same size and contains the same types of values.
> - ...

Comment: This isn’t the best cite as §4.10.2 applies to verification of classes without `StackMapTable` attributes only, in other words, is irrelevant for recently compiled code. You should refer to [§4.9.2. Structural Constraints (bullet 2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.2) instead: “*If an instruction can be executed along several different execution paths, the operand stack must have the same depth (§2.6.2) prior to the execution of the instruction, regardless of the path taken*”, as this applies to all class files.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Bytecode verification enforces that the stack size is constant at any given instruction, regardless of control flow. (It also enforces that the types are compatible). Therefore, this is true not only of bytecode derived from compiled Java, but any valid bytecode at all.

Comment: Interesting. I assume that this is done for safety reasons. What would be a malicious thing that could happen if that was not the case?

Comment: @Thilo Without type checking, malicious Java bytecode could trivially subvert the JVM and execute arbitrary native code. This is primarily a concern with Java applets, which attempt in-process sandboxing.

Comment: @Thilo: Apart from that, it is also useful for efficiency. In the current system, the operand stack is essentially another set of registers that are just accessed implicitly. With a dynamic stack, it would be much harder to JIT efficiently.